# java using this word is optional or not?

Tags: java, this, keyword, option-type

Is using the keyword `this` optional in Java? Or do I have to use it? And when it is not optional?
In the following code it does not affect my application, regardless of how many instances of `Employee` I made.
The `print` method prints Employee details without anything wrong even if details do not match.

```
public class Employee {
    String name;
    int Salary;
    int pension;
    String workPlace;
    String teleNo;
    int age;

    void printDetails(){
        System.out.println("Name is :  "+this.name );
        System.out.println("age is  :  "+this.age );
        System.out.println("WorkPlace is  :  "+this.workPlace );
        System.out.println("Salary is  :  "+Salary );
        System.out.println("Pension is  :  "+this.pension );
        System.out.println("Telephone No. is  :  "+this.teleNo );
        System.out.println("age is  :  "+Integer.toString(age) );
    }
}

public class Main extends Employee {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Employee obj=new Employee();
        obj.age=25;
        obj.name="Yasser";
        obj.pension=100_000;
        obj.teleNo="xxx_xxxx";
        obj.workPlace="Egypt";
        obj.Salary=1000000;

        obj.printDetails();
        Employee obj1=new Employee();
        obj1.age=29;
        obj1.name="asser";
        obj1.pension=100_000;
        obj1.teleNo="xxx_xxxx";
        obj1.workPlace="rgypt";
        obj1.Salary=2000000;
        obj1.printDetails();
    }
}
```

Comment: you can easily find more info by googling: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html

Comment: `this` always refers to current instance of a class. So you need not use unless there's a method local variable having with same name but you want to make use of your instance variable, then we explicitly prefix  our variable name with `this` to tell the compiler that we need to use instance variable instead of a local variable in that case

Answer (score 11):

It's always optional **unless** you are referencing a field which has the same name as a local variable. For example:

```
class Sample
{
    int value;

    void method(int value)
    {
        this.value = value; //this is required
    }
}
```

If this is not the case, then using `this` behaves identically to referencing the variable directly.

Answer (score 4):

`this` in Java is optional, unless you have a local variable or parameter of the same name, in which case the variable name will be referring to the latter.

```
public class Employee {

    private String name = "one";

    public void printDetails() {
        String name = "two";
        System.out.println(this.name); // "one"
        System.out.println(name); // "two"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`this` is always optional with the exception of referring to a field which is named the same both locally and globally. e.g:

```
class test
{
    int varname; //global 

    public void testMethod(int varname)
    {
        this.varname=varname; //this.varname refers to the declaration within the class, not the method (the global 'varname' variable)

    }
```

As others has mentioned, it's always worth reading the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html).

Also, `this` refers to the *current* object. As per the documentation, this means that `this` refers to the *current* object whose method or constructor is being called. So, for example, if you had some code that declared a Swing component and attached an action listener to it, code within that action listener would refer to the action listener if prefixed with the `this` keyword:

```
swingJButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        this.actionPerformed(e); // <-- refers to "new ActionListener()" object above
    } });
```

For simplicity, it's best to just avoid using the keyword unless you have to. Some programmers prefer using the same variable names within different scopes - its rather common in so called setter methods, others do not - that's down to preference; whichever you choose, be aware of that `this` is referring to.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use 'this' when you have variables in different 'scopes' which have the same name. So if you have an instance variable and a variable in a method which are called the same thing, you must prefix the instance variable with 'this', otherwise the local variable will override the instance variable.

Otherwise it is optional and is a matter of personal preference.

Some people like the scope of a variable to be explicit in the code - others think this is clutter and unnecessary.

Personally, I would aim to not have the same names for variables in different scopes if possible.